# Updating data when fetching

Tags: postgresql, architecture, backend

Is it possible to fetch data and update it once a time constraint has been met? Originally, my implementation was a cron job that regularly updated the data in my PostgreSQL table every minute on the minute after selecting all the rows that met the time constraint. (Meaning the job always ran at 12:00, 12:01, 12:02, etc)

However, I now have to include a new use case that there *could* be data to be updated every second, but not always. (Meaning the constraint can not be on 12:00:00, 12:00:46 or 12:12:12) The straightforward answer here would be to modify  the cron job, but a cron running every second on a live database doesn't seem prudent, and maybe not possible?

My first proposed solution was to trigger an update based on the time constraint whenever a user fetches data

`Backend fetch -> DB select -> DB trigger update -> DB returns data -> Backend returns data`

but Postgre does not allow for trigger functions on SELECT statements.

My second alternative is to simply do a separate call to update the data whenever it is fetched.

`Backend fetch -> DB select -> Backend update data -> DB update data -> Backend returns data`

But while both of these solutions gives the illusion of real-time updates (such as if a user refreshes before and after the time constraint), neither of these solutions actually update the data until it is fetched, which ends up becoming kind of Schrodinger-y.

My third and final proposal was to include the frontend into it

`Backend fetch -> Backend returns data -> Frontend timer -> Backend fetch when constraint is met`

But I feel like that introduces more variables, so I'm currently leaning the most towards solution #2. However, I feel like I might be overlooking an obvious solution and am trying to over-engineer a simple problem, so I am open to all and any resources or solutions.

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you like to update the data based on a time constraint? When no-one uses this data, there is no reason to update it. You could do an UPDATE and use RETURNING to fetch the results. But I would try to avoid an update when there is no need for it.

Comment: User defined flash sales. Originally, the sales were pre-scheduled, so they ended on the minute A 5 minute sale scheduled at 11:53:29 would be from 12:01-12:06 on the minute. But we're looking to add ad-hoc flash sales that the user can start instantly. A 5 minute sale starting at 12:01:34 would then need to end at 12:06:34, not 12:06 or 12:07

Comment: So you don’t need any update at all. Just fetch the records that are within the timeframe and you’re done

Comment: After the time's up, I would need an update to set the sale status as "Finished" for the seller's dashboard, or mark price changes on items' in the shopping cart that was added as part of the flash deal

Comment: It’s finished because time is up, no need to update the record. You could do it when the seller requests the current status, but from a technical standpoint there is no need for it.

Comment: So your advice is to use my second proposal, and just update the status of the sale as "Finished" the next time the seller loads their sales? Thank you.

Comment: The solution was nicely summarized here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/439749/updating-data-when-fetching